# Apple requires "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" description to info.plist with Parse-iOS-SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, parsing, push-notification, applet

I use parse for Push Notifications purpose. When I uploaded the binary to App Store  Connect with Parse SDK installed apple sends me an automated message like bellow. This issue have been a month from now. When i removed the SDK from pod i don' t delivered this message. I hav no use location to my apps.

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your  app
> XXXXX. Your delivery was successful, but you  may wish to correct the
> following issues in your next delivery:
>
> "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File. Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The
> app's Info.plist file should contain a
> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose
> string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the  data.
> Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store  that access
> user data will be required to include a purpose  string.If you're
> using external libraries or SDKs, they may  reference APIs that
> require a purpose string. While your app might  not use these APIs, a
> purpose string is still required. You can  contact the developer of
> the library or SDK and request they  release a version of their code
> that doesn't contain the APIs.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or   Application
> Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team"

Also I have the same issue with more than one project.

I mentioned the issue on official github of SDK but they tell me that it isn't a issue with SDK.

Has anyone else the same issue? What text can i add to info.plist to make apple approve my project.

Comment: Since the Parse library references CLLocationManager, the automatic rejection is being triggered. You should be able to add any text to that key in info.plist to satisfy the automatic check and since your app doesn't actually use location, Apple won't actually see that text anyway.

Comment: lots of users are having the same issue with NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription. You can add the following in your plist. 

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your explanation</string>

Comment: I uploaded the same binary with outdated Parse-iOS-SDK on July and i think that the automated message dint' t be sent to me. 

I added the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, but i try to find a solution to make apple system stopping reject the binary. I will report the issue at apple bug system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed CoreLocation.framework from from linked libraries. Also I deleted PFLocationManager.h and PFLocationManager.m files and I commented CCLocation objects from PFGeoPoint.h/m, FPolygon.h/m and Parse.h.

I uploaded the binary successfully without delivered email from Apple System.